# Does the function Socket.Select() in C# use epoll when OS in linux?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I know there are three ways in I/O multiplexing: select, poll and epoll in Linux.I can't figure out if the C# function Socket.Select() just use select or it will use epoll When OS support.

If it don't use epoll which function does?Such as selector.select in java,it will use epoll when OS support

Comment: Test it out... if it doesnt just pinvoke the appropriate epoll methods

Comment: You do know that .NET is open source these days, right, and so you can go and read the code and know one way or the other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.net core uses epoll for async `Socket.xxxAsync` operations.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/

For Socket.Select() call chain is `Socket.Select() -> SocketPal.Unix.cs -> SelectViaPoll -> Interop.Sys.Poll -> Interop.Poll -> [DllImport(Libraries.SystemNative, EntryPoint = "SystemNative_Poll")]    internal static extern unsafe Error Poll(PollEvent* pollEvents, uint eventCount, int timeout, uint* triggered); -> Common_Poll ->  inline static int32_t Common_Poll(PollEvent* pollEvents, uint32_t eventCount, int32_t milliseconds, uint32_t* triggered)  -> poll()`

For async ops:
 `Socket.RecieveFromAsync() -> SocketAsyncContext.Unix ReceiveFromAsync() -> _receiveQueue.StartAsyncOperation() -> SocketAsyncEngine.TryRegister();`

Then we go to `SocketAsyncEngine.EventLoop() -> Interop.SocketEvent.cs _> SystemNative_WaitForSocketEvents -> WaitForSocketEventsInner -> epoll()`

See PAL code on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Native/Unix/System.Native/pal_networking.c). If the system has epoll it will be compiled in.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.When I try to read the code,I find epoll used in these two classes SocketAsyncEngine.Unix.cs and SocketAsyncContext.Unix.cs. In my opinion,epoll is used by the other function instead of Socket.Select().If I am right?If it so,which function use epoll() actually.

Comment: Sorry for confusing answer, updated text, hopefully it is now more clear =)